# How can I do optional pdf generation?

Tags: macros

I am experimenting with dynamic citations.

I want four options:

1. default no dynamics;
2. a click on citation goes to bibliography;
3. a click on the external citation goes to the internet;
4. both 2 and 3.

Something like: if this, do something, else do another thing.

**Edit** I only want a method to include/exclude portions of the LaTeX. I already have a handle on the dynamics.

Comment: 2-4 seem like they would be taken care of by a bibliography such as ``biblatex`` with ``hyperref`` loaded. Assuming you mean bibliography citations. 
Or do you mean textual quotes (full passages ?).
And what do you mean with ``include/exclude`` portions of the LaTeX ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to enable/disable parts of your code programmatically. If so, you may want to create two toggles, each associated to one type of link. Here is a skeletal solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{citationlinks}   % false by default
\newtoggle{internetlinks}   % false by default

\toggletrue{citationlinks}  % <--- comment that in or out
\toggletrue{internetlinks}  % <--- comment that in or out

\iftoggle{citationlinks}{%
    % if true, do this
}{%
    % if false, do that
}

\iftoggle{internetlinks}{%
    % if true, do this
}{%
    % if false, do that
}

\begin{document}
%...
\end{document}
```